# Emgu CV видит фару, но не видит номер автомобиля

Tags: c#, распознавание-символов, распознавание

Имеется код который должен распознавать номера, он как бы работает, как бы нет.
Может кто-то сталкивался или работал в этой системе и поможет допилить имеющийся код, чтоб он хотя бы +/- распознавал.
Думал как-нибудь добавить шаблон, например: с начало идёт одна буква, потом три цифры, затем две буквы , или три цифры и три буквы, в зависимости от первого символа.(Но я не знаю как реализовать данный шаблон).
Еще думал обучить как-нибудь, но не знаю как, штудил весь гугл, не чего путного не нашёл, либо плохо искал. Снизу будут фотокарточки, на которых надо распознать номер, а так же код отвечающий за распознавание.
Так же не работает ocr.SetVariable();
Kод который отвечает за распознавание.

```
namespace CarNumberRecognizer
{
    class NumberPlateRecognizer : DisposableObject
    {
        private Tesseract ocr;
        public NumberPlateRecognizer(string tessdataPath, string lang)
        {
            ocr = new Tesseract(tessdataPath, lang, OcrEngineMode.TesseractLstmCombined); 
            ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890");
        }
        public List<string> DetectLicensePlates(IInputArray image,
            List<IInputOutputArray> licensePlateImageList,
            List<IInputOutputArray> filteredLicensePlateImageList,
            List<RotatedRect> detectedLicensePlateRegionList)
        {
            List<string> licenses = new List<string>();
            using (UMat canny = new UMat())  
            {
                using (UMat gray = new UMat())
                {
                    using (VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint())
                    {                    
                        CvInvoke.CvtColor(image, canny, ColorConversion.Bgra2Gray); 
                        CvInvoke.Canny(canny, gray, 100, 50, 3, false); 
                        int[,] hierachy = CvInvoke.FindContourTree(gray, contours, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple); 
                       FindLicensePlate(contours, hierachy, 0, canny, gray,
                          licensePlateImageList, filteredLicensePlateImageList, detectedLicensePlateRegionList,
                            licenses);
                    }
                }
            }
            return licenses;
        }
        //Создаём список с распознанными госзнаками в текстовом представлении и список с прямоугольниками в которых есть госзнаки
        private void FindLicensePlate(VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours,
              int[,] hierachy,
              int index,
              IInputArray gray,
              IInputArray canny,
              List<IInputOutputArray> licensePlateImageList,
              List<IInputOutputArray> filteredLicensePlateImageList,
              List<RotatedRect> detectedLicensePlateRegionList,
              List<string> licenses)
        {
            for (; index >= 0; index = hierachy[index, 0])
            {
              int numberOfChildren = GetNumberOfChildren(hierachy, index);

                if (numberOfChildren == 0)
                    continue;
                using (VectorOfPoint contour = contours[index])
                {
                    if (CvInvoke.ContourArea(contour) > 200)
                    {
                        if (numberOfChildren < 3)
                       {
                            FindLicensePlate(contours, hierachy, hierachy[index, 2], gray, canny,
                                licensePlateImageList, filteredLicensePlateImageList, detectedLicensePlateRegionList,
                                licenses);
                           continue;
                        }
                        RotatedRect box = CvInvoke.MinAreaRect(contour);
                        if (box.Angle < -45.0) 
                        {
                            float tmp = box.Size.Width;
                            box.Size.Width = box.Size.Height;
                            box.Size.Height = tmp;
                            box.Angle += 90.0f;
                        }
                        else if (box.Angle > 45.0)
                        {
                            float tmp = box.Size.Width;

                            box.Size.Width = box.Size.Height;
                            box.Size.Height = tmp;
                            box.Angle -= 90.0f;
                        }
                        double whRatio = (double)box.Size.Width / box.Size.Height;
                        if (!(3.0 < whRatio && whRatio < 10.0))
                        {
                            if (hierachy[index, 2] > 0)
                            {
                                FindLicensePlate(contours, hierachy, hierachy[index, 2], gray, canny,
                                    licensePlateImageList, filteredLicensePlateImageList, detectedLicensePlateRegionList,
                                    licenses);
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        using (UMat tmp1 = new UMat())
                        {
                            using (UMat tmp2 = new UMat())
                            {
                                PointF[] srcCorners = box.GetVertices();

                                PointF[] destCorners = new PointF[]
                                {
                                    new PointF(0, box.Size.Height - 1),
                                    new PointF(0, 0),
                                    new PointF(box.Size.Width - 1, 0),
                                    new PointF(box.Size.Width - 1, box.Size.Height - 1)
                                };

                                using (Mat rot = CvInvoke.GetAffineTransform(srcCorners, destCorners))
                                {
                                    CvInvoke.WarpAffine(gray, tmp1, rot, Size.Round(box.Size)); 
                                }

                                Size approxSize = new Size(240, 80); 

                                double scale = Math.Min(approxSize.Width / box.Size.Width,
                                    approxSize.Height / box.Size.Height);

                                Size newSize = new Size((int)Math.Round(box.Size.Width * scale),
                                    (int)Math.Round(box.Size.Height * scale));

                                CvInvoke.Resize(tmp1, tmp2, newSize, 0, 0, Inter.Cubic); 

                                int edgePixelSize = 3;
                               Rectangle newRoi = new Rectangle(new Point(edgePixelSize, edgePixelSize),
                                   tmp2.Size - new Size(2 * edgePixelSize, 2 * edgePixelSize));
                                UMat plate = new UMat(tmp2, newRoi);
                                UMat filteredPlate = FilterPlate(plate);
                                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                                using (UMat tmp = filteredPlate.Clone())
                                {
                                    ocr.SetImage(tmp);
                                    ocr.Recognize();
                                    stringBuilder.Append(ocr.GetUTF8Text());
                                }
                                licenses.Add(stringBuilder.ToString());
                                licensePlateImageList.Add(plate);
                             filteredLicensePlateImageList.Add(filteredPlate);
                                detectedLicensePlateRegionList.Add(box);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        private int GetNumberOfChildren(int[,] hierarchy, int index)
        {
            index = hierarchy[index, 2];

            if (index < 0)
                return 0;

            int count = 1;

            while (hierarchy[index, 0] > 0)
            {
                count++;

                index = hierarchy[index, 0];
            }

            return count;
        }
     
         private static UMat FilterPlate(UMat plate)
        {
            UMat thresh = new UMat();

            CvInvoke.Threshold(plate, thresh, 120, 255, ThresholdType.BinaryInv);

            Size plateSize = plate.Size;

            using (Mat plateMask = new Mat(plateSize.Height, plateSize.Width, DepthType.Cv8U, 1))
            {
                using (Mat plateCanny = new Mat())
                {
                    using (VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint())
                    {
                        plateMask.SetTo(new MCvScalar(255.0));

                        CvInvoke.Canny(plate, plateCanny, 100, 50); 

                       CvInvoke.FindContours(plateCanny, contours, null, RetrType.External, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

                        int count = contours.Size;

                        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                        {
                            using (VectorOfPoint contour = contours[i])
                            {
                               Rectangle rect = CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(contour);
                       
                              if (rect.Height > (plateSize.Height >> 1))
                              {
                                  rect.X -= 1;
                                  rect.Y -= 1;
                       
                                  rect.Width += 2;
                                  rect.Height += 2;
                       
                                  Rectangle roi = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, plate.Size);
                       
                                  rect.Intersect(roi);
                       
                                  CvInvoke.Rectangle(plateMask, rect, new MCvScalar(), -1);
                              }
                            }
                        }

                        thresh.SetTo(new MCvScalar(), plateMask);
                    }
                }
            }

            CvInvoke.Erode(thresh, thresh, null,  new Point(-1, -1), 1 , BorderType.Constant, CvInvoke.MorphologyDefaultBorderValue);
            CvInvoke.Dilate(thresh, thresh, null, new Point(-1, -1), 1, BorderType.Constant, CvInvoke.MorphologyDefaultBorderValue);

            return thresh;
        } 

        protected override void DisposeObject()
        {
            ocr.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Весь проект вряд ли кто-то будет тут разбирать, это вам на фриланс надо. Если приведёте кусок кода, который не работает, может кто и посмотрит.

Comment: @CrazyElf , так я скинул файл с кусочком кодом, там строк без пробелом и прочего где-то 170-180,.

Comment: По правилам код надо прикреплять к вопросу: сегодня код на яндекс:диске есть - завтра нету.

Comment: Ищите внутри контура-кандидата на номерной знак темные элементы. Хотя бы считайте дисперсию внутри подозрительного контура..

Comment: @Алекс , теперь видит, но текст выводится не корректно, может просто две рандомные буквы и какуй-нибудь чёрточку